# DELETE method does not work with PHP + Slim Framework + nginx

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I have run into a strange issue with my server setup. I have nginx installed with php-fastcgi and MySQL running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am using Slim Framework for running my website. For some reason, the DELETE method does not work for any URL endpoint on the server. I just get this error when I fire a DELETE request through Postman:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: You are not allowed to access the document you requested.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
```

This is happening for all domains and all endpoints on the server. I don't see anything in the access logs either. The method was working earlier so I am guessing some update changed things.

Any idea which process would generate this error and how can this be fixed?

Comment: maybe it's a routing issue, maybe you need to define that some routes should accept the delete method, not sure how slim works, but that's what i can think of.

Comment: The endpoint works locally. So definitely not due to Slim. Any known PHP/nginx configuration causes this problem on Ubuntu?

Comment: check folder/file permissions

Comment: Definitely not due to that. GET/POST etc. all work. In fact the ONLY method that does not work is DELETE.

Comment: @Abhinav, did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that my network was blocking all DELETE calls.

It started working when I tested it on a different router and network.

Comment: Almost the same situation here. Turned out to be a problem with my network connection.